# Return a dataframe as result Flask

Tags: python, dataframe, flask

I use flask.
I want to return a dataframe as result.
But I get this error.

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a DataFrame.
```

Comment: Did you know that the return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable?

Comment: of course , but I want to return a dataframe

Answer (score 1):

set header of response as **text/csv**

```
resp.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
resp.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv"
return resp
```